# Do I need a colon or a semicolon in the following case?

Tags: grammar, punctuation

> For the next few seconds, I watched Aiko read the letter with her lips
>   agape -- lips that steadily curled up into a smile. One that infected
>   me **[: / ;]** before realizing it, I found myself smiling too, enjoying a
>   happiness that came from someone else's heart. It was my first time.

For some reason, I can't decide whether I should use a colon or a semicolon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colon is more often used to indicate a pause before saying something that *justifies* or *adds detail* to the previous statement.

> There are three reasons cats are better than dogs: 1) they are cheaper, 2) they are quieter, and 3) they are controlling my mind.

Meanwhile, the semicolon is used to join two complete sentences which would otherwise be separated by a period, or modified to join with a conjunction.

> It was her first time swimming in the ocean; she was having great fun until she swallowed a mouthful of salt water.

*That being said* ... with creative writing, you use whatever punctuation sounds best reflects your own "inner voice".  You can throw the "rules" (such as they are) out the window.

Personally, I prefer the long (or "em") dash to either the colon or semicolon.   To me, the dash better conveys the feeling of *passionate narrative*, while the others feel more like *detached exposition*.

You already know how to use the dash -- but since you don't want too many dashes in a single paragraph, I would rewrite the first sentence to remove the dash there, and instead use it in the second sentence.

> For the next few seconds, I watched Aiko read the letter with her lips agape, lips that steadily curled up into a smile. One that infected me -- before realizing it, I found myself smiling too, enjoying a happiness that came from someone else's heart. It was my first time.

It's *your* story, though, and if you think a colon sounds better, use that:

> One that infected me: before realizing it, I found myself smiling too, enjoying a happiness that came from someone else's heart.

There's also the ellipsis (...):

> One that infected me ... before realizing it, (etc.)

Answer (score 1):

The style and content of this passage suggests fiction. Either punctuation mark could be used in this context. One clue that we are not dealing with standard usage is that either one would leave a fragment before it, compared to:

> (The smile was) one that infected me

That said, I believe a colon would be marginally more typical. The uses can be subtle, but here's how I would compare them in this situation:

A **colon** is used to introduce a second part of the sentence that explains, justifies, illustrates, or reframes the first part.

> When I came home to Canada, I saw that spring had come: the flowers were in bloom, the birds were singing on the low branches of new trees.

Here, we assert that spring had come, and then we give the proof of that same claim.

A **semicolon** is used to connect two parts of the sentence that are closely logically connected, but where the second is less a restatement of the first — it's either paired with it or uses the first as a stepping stone and goes on to the next ensuing thought.

> In my grandparents' childhood, nobody owned a car; everyone got around by horse and buggy.

Notice how the second part doesn't reiterate the claim that nobody owned a car, but answers an unasked question: "Then how did they get around?"

In your sentence, it seems to me that you're trying to do the former more than the latter. You say that the smile infected you, and then you illustrate what you mean by that.

But the logical connections expressed here clearly have a lot of overlap, so although one may be more appropriate, either would certainly fit the context (again, especially when stylistically free as fiction is).